# Excluding multiple items from Get-ChildItem using Powershell version 4

Tags: powershell, filtering, powershell-4.0, get-childitem

I'm iterating through a directory tree but trying to filter out a number of things.

This is my cobbled together code;

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $pathName -recurse -Filter index.aspx* -Exclude */stocklist/* | ? {$_.fullname -NotMatch "\\\s*_"} | Where {$_.FullName -notlike "*\assets\*" -or $_.FullName -notlike ".bk"}
```

- Remove the name index.aspx from the returned item.
- I want to filter out any file that starts with and underscore.
- Exclude anything that contains */stocklist/* in its path.
- Exclude anything that contains */assets/* in its path.
- And exclude anything that contains *.bk* in its path.

This is working for everything but for the .bk in it's path. I'm pretty sure it's a syntax error on my part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming .bk is an extension? Use "*.bk".

Comment: No it's not an extension. It's part of the path name EG c:/foo/something.bk/anotherthing/. Thanks.

Comment: Just use `-notmatch '\.bk\b'`

Comment: Just a note on your last `Where{ }` statement, you want to use `-and` instead of `-or` because `-or` passes through anything where one of the comparisons returns `$true`. So if it has `\assets\` in the path, but not `.bk` the second condition will resolve as `$true` and it will pass the filter, which is not your intent. To use it like you did you would need to not use the negative comparator, and then put the whole thing in parethesis and do a `-not` (or `!`) against it like this `Where { ! ($_.FullName -like "*\assets\*" -or $_.FullName -like "*.bk*")}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regex string and use `-notmatch` on the file's .DirectoryName property in a Where-Object clause to exclude the files you don't need:

```
$excludes = '/stocklist/', '/assets/', '.bk'
# create a regex of the folders to exclude
# each folder will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
$notThese = ($excludes | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

Get-ChildItem -Path $pathName -Filter 'index.aspx*' -File -Recurse |
Where-Object{ $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $notThese -and $_.Name -notmatch '^\s*_' }
```

Comment: They also wanted to exclude files that start with an underscore, so update to `{ $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $notThese -and $_.Name -notmatch '^\s*_' }` for your `Where-Object` scriptblock.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Ow.. totally missed that. Thanks for this, I have updated my answer. (although the Filter 'index.aspx*' suggested by the OP should have taken care of that.)

Comment: ...and *I* missed that bit. You're completely right, the `-filter 'index.aspx*'` would totally take care of that.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes, but that filter might be just an example and could easily be changed to `'*index.aspx*'`.. In that case, your addition catches that, so thanks again.